# Modern vertical layout for Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, apple-mail, email-client, layout

It's weird that I haven't been able to find relevant information anywhere. Basically what I want is a modern vertical layout for the inbox of Thunderbird. That is to say, the message sender and subject should not be crammed into one line, but displayed in a taller row, in the same manner as Apple Mail/Airmail. The current manner in which messages are displayed in Thunderbird under vertical layout makes it very uneasy on the eyes, and I'm not really a fan of horizontal layouts.

Thunderbird:

[image: Thunderbird Vertical Layout]

vs.

Apple Mail:

[image: Apple Mail Layout]

Comment: This would be great, there doesn't appear to be an extension that does this.

Comment: See this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441414) and [this thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2976881). Basically, Mozilla doesn't want to support XUL anymore, so people gave up on working on it.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an extension that does this, but there's an easy workaround which does what you want:

With a message selected press **Ctrl-A** to select all messages. The right hand pane then displays all the messages selected, with a summary of their content. (From here you can simply click on a message's subject to go to it).

Comment: It's the closest TBird gets at the moment but it is also a really really weak substitute. :(

Answer (score -7):

Yes there is an option for that.

**View** > **Layout** > and choose **Vertical Layout**.

Comment: The question claims that this setting results in the layout shown, which is what isn't desired.  It would be helpful if you could add an image to your answer to illustrate the result.

Comment: Did you read the question? There's apparently something called "vertical layout" but not "modern" vertical layout I indicated.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer completely misses the point :(, which is about being able to display subject and sender(s) of a message in separate lines inside the messages list.